# Parallelizing apply function in pandas taking longer than expected

Tags: pandas, python-multiprocessing

I have a simple cleaner function which removes special characters from a dataframe (and other preprocessing stuff). My dataset is huge and I want to make use of multiprocessing to improve performance. My idea was to break the dataset into chunks and run this cleaner function in parallel on each of them.
I used dask library and also the multiprocessing module from python. However, it seems like the application is stuck and is taking longer than running with a single core.

This is my code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def parallelize_dataframe(df, func):
    df_split = np.array_split(df, num_partitions)
    pool = Pool(num_cores)
    df = pd.concat(pool.map(func, df_split))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return df

def process_columns(data):
    for i in data.columns:
        data[i] = data[i].apply(cleaner_func)
    return data

mydf2 = parallelize_dataframe(mydf, process_columns)
```

I can see from the resource monitor that all cores are being used, but as I said before, the application is stuck.

**P.S. 
I ran this on windows server 2012 (where the issue happens). Running this code on unix env, I was actually able to see some benefit from the multiprocessing library.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: something seems off to me in your df = pd.concat, pool.close(), pool.join() lines. Why join after the df that you're returning has already been assigned two lines above?

Comment: These days I would do this using [dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/) and get rid of the manual multiprocessing headhache

Comment: @flyingmeatball. I see your point, concat is not actually needed. However, the problem remains even removing this function call.